# How to set Atom prettier tab size?

Tags: atom-editor, prettier, tab-size

When I disable the prettier-atom package, the tab size is 4, but when I enable the prettier package, formatting a file causes the tab size to decrease to 2. My prettier version is 0.56.4; I was able to directly modify the tab size of prettier in my prettier package settings on a previous version, but now the option is gone. I've looked at other questions about tab size, but haven't found where to directly edit the prettier default tab size.

Any help or direction is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the tab length in the latest **prettier-atom** package is 2 and there is no way to change it.

The atom-beautify package https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify uses the standard Tab Length from your Atom settings.